# Android Custom Round Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have seen a lot of tutorials and video on **How to make a custom progress bar**. They show only by changing the color, the style or the elements. No one shows  with a runnable picture.

I don't understand that how developers match their progress with the custom view or how they make a picture's part **runnable**.
Think of a circle view and it runs just like a progress.
But how?
Or how can I define the part which I want to run with the java code?

Please don't pass way the question. I am very very much interested to know and to implement it.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried yet and what will I try! If a man has no idea what is he going to do so how he can do that? The same thing happens with me. I don't know where I will start?

Comment: And if you are unable to show a full tutorial then if you don't mind, you can give the links of these tutorials

Comment: That will be helpful

Comment: I usually visit there.

Comment: My main purpose is to know how we can make a picture runable

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://github.com/grmaciel/two-level-circular-progress-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but the following links may help you:

[How To Make Circle Custom Progress Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android)

[Progress bar with image in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964799/progress-bar-with-image-in-center)

[Custom circular ProgressBar with image in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229490/custom-circular-progressbar-with-image-in-center)

[How to change color in circular progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337613/how-to-custom-circular-progress-bar-color)

This is the main source of all things Android.

[Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) at the site **android.com**

You need to download Android Studio (or eclipse, but I prefer Android studio and am the one answering the question).

[Get Started with Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)

This is another good resource http://www.tutorialspoint.com//android/index.htm.

I also subscribe to this. [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](https://commonsware.com/Android/)

Here is a tutorial [Custom Progress Bar In Android](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html) that is more pertinent to your request.

When you have more specific questions, you are welcome to come to Stack Overflow with them.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But those are not my answers bro. I use developer.android.com and tutorialspoint.com. But not the busy coder's guide

Comment: And you preferred the stuffs are all for the beginners only. But I am not a beginner.

Comment: OK ah, if you don't mind see this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=xPY3gcAJzLk and tell me how can I implement this in an application

Comment: For example that picture has now 65% as it's current progress. So how can I make that picture runable? That's my question

Comment: Ah, not bad now. Got my apart answer.

Comment: Cheers. Actually your 1st links link of github library worked for me. Yes, I think so